# React Router 4 links are working but components are not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

Dears, This is main component where I import other components and making Route object, Links are working history object are changing as well but components are not rendered (I don't use redux here). Console doesn't through any error as well

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './components/Main';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Register from './components/Register';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className='container'>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                        <Link to="/">Main</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <Route  path="/" Component={Main}/>
                    <Route path="/login" Component={Login}/>
                    <Route path="/register" Component={Register}/>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" Component={Dashboard}/>


                </div> 
            </Router>

        ) 
    }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making `Component` lowercase, like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={Main}/>
<Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
<Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
<Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
```

Comment: That extra space hurts my ocd soul

Comment: @Galupuf ah! I didn't see that when I answered lol, I'll remove it

Comment: @Galupuf ahahah

Comment: @Smarticles101 Bless you child

Comment: @Galupuf it's funny cause I am a child lmao

Comment: lol missed that one haha, need to push to react repo it supposed to through an error